# Should I use uint if my function is logically intended to return only natural numbers?

Tags: c#, sql, coding-style, types, unsigned

Let's consider a function which gets a person's birth date and returns his age (in whole years). In case of the date is in future it throws an exception. What type should it return - uint or int? uint seems logical as a natural constraint. Or is it better to use more usual int?

Comment: Then why not `ushort`? Or do you expect someone to live 4 billion years? Or how about `byte`? That will surely cover a lifespan. (Go with `int`.)

Comment: @anthony-pegram, I hope our science is going to let us meet after 4 billion years, and I am sure C# 2billions.0 is going to be so coooool that it's worth waiting ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the unsigned numbers are not CLS-compliant, so in general: No, don't use them.
Certainly not in public interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

yes use uint because uint allows for a greater range of digits about 2 times more range so if all your numbers are positive are they are large use uint, but if you think they could possibly be negative and they can never be big (1000000 is big) then use int as that is more safe and error proof for variable values.